# Jquery if else hamburger

Tags: jquery, css, hamburger-menu

My code is not working. This is for a hamburger menu

```
$("#nav-button").on("click", function(){
    if
    ($("#list-nav").css('display') == 'none');
    $("#list-nav").slideDown(300);

    else 

    ($("#list-nav").css('display') == 'block');
    $("#list-nav").slideUp(300);
    $(".hamburger").removeClass( "is-active" )

});
```

Comment: [`if...else statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#if...else_statement)

Comment: I think you are pretty new to Javascript as well. Read how `if...else` works, and you'll know why your code isn't working.

Comment: Some HTML would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if-else statement seems incorrect

```
$("#nav-button").on("click", function(){
  if($("#list-nav").css('display') == 'none') {
    $("#list-nav").slideDown(300);
  } else {
    $("#list-nav").slideUp(300);
    $(".hamburger").removeClass( "is-active" )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Need some brackets. Try this:

```
$("#nav-button").on("click", function() {
    if ($("#list-nav").is(':hidden')) {
        $("#list-nav").slideDown(300);
    } else {
        $("#list-nav").slideUp(300);
        $(".hamburger").removeClass( "is-active" );
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($("#list-nav").css("display") == "none")
            {
                alert("Hide");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Show")
            }
```